# Why does auto return type change the overload resolution?

Tags: c++, auto, c++14, return-type-deduction

Thanks to `decltype` as a return type, C++11 made it extremely easy to introduce decorators.  For instance, consider this class:

```
struct base
{
  void fun(unsigned) {}
};
```

I want to decorate it with additional features, and since I will do that several times with different kinds of decorations, I first introduce a `decorator` class that simply forwards everything to `base`.  In the real code, this is done via `std::shared_ptr` so that I can remove decorations and recover the "naked" object, and everything is templated.

```
#include <utility> // std::forward
struct decorator
{
  base b;

  template <typename... Args>
  auto
  fun(Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(b.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  {
    return b.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

Perfect forwarding and `decltype` are just wonderful.  In the real code, I actually use a macro that just needs the name of the function, all the rest is boilerplate.

And then, I can introduce a `derived` class that adds features to my object (`derived` is improper, agreed, but it helps understanding that `derived` is-a-kind of `base`, albeit not via inheritance).

```
struct foo_t {};
struct derived : decorator
{
  using decorator::fun; // I want "native" fun, and decorated fun.
  void fun(const foo_t&) {}
};

int main()
{
  derived d;
  d.fun(foo_t{});
}
```

Then C++14 came, with return type deduction, which allows to write things in a simpler way: remove the `decltype` part of the forwarding function:

```
struct decorator
{
  base b;

  template <typename... Args>
  auto
  fun(Args&&... args)
  {
    return b.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

And *then* it breaks.  Yes, at least according to both GCC and Clang, this:

```
  template <typename... Args>
  auto
  fun(Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(b.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  {
    return b.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

is not equivalent to this (and the issue is not `auto` vs. `decltype(auto)`):

```
  template <typename... Args>
  auto
  fun(Args&&... args)
  {
    return b.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

The overload resolution seems to be completely different and it ends like this:

```
clang++-mp-3.5 -std=c++1y main.cc
main.cc:19:18: error: no viable conversion from 'foo_t' to 'unsigned int'
    return b.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cc:32:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'decorator::fun<foo_t>' requested here
  d.fun(foo_t{});
    ^
main.cc:7:20: note: passing argument to parameter here
  void fun(unsigned) {}
                   ^
```

I understand the failure: my call (`d.fun(foo_t{})`) does not match perfectly with the signature of `derived::fun`, which takes a `const foo_t&`, so the very eager `decorator::fun` kicks in (we know how `Args&&...` is extremely impatient to bind to anything that does not match perfectly).  So it forwards this to `base::fun` which can't deal with `foo_t`.

If I change `derived::fun` to take a `foo_t` instead of `const foo_t&`, then it works as expected, which shows that indeed here the problem is that there is a competition between `derived::fun` and `decorator::fun`.

However why the heck does this show with return-type deduction???  And more precisely *why* was this behavior chosen by the committee?

To make things easier, on Coliru:

- [the version with `decltype` that works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af2d798dd93ee4f5)
- [the version with type deduction that fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c627ff3d74ff174)

Thanks!

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks for the tip.  Here, it makes no difference.

Comment: `decltype(b.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...))` in trailing return type works as *Expression SFINAE*, while neither `auto` nor `decltype(auto)` does

Comment: To add to Piotr S.'s comment: that's intentional, too. For SFINAE to work, the return type must be available without looking at the function body. To enable returning lambdas, the return type must not be available without looking at the function body. A decision was made that enabling returning lambdas was more important than SFINAE.

Comment: Agreed. I just read [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710461/why-does-auto-return-type-change-the-overload-resolution/26710615?noredirect=1#comment42012726_26710615) and learnt from it. :|

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just look at this call:

```
d.fun(foo_t{});
```

You create a temporary (i.e rvalue), passing it as argument to the function. Now what do you think happens?

- It first *attempts* to bind to the argument `Arg&&`, as it can accept rvalue **but**  due to invalid return type deduction (*which again due to `foo_t` cannot convert into `unsigned int`, because of which `b.fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` turns out to be invalid expression*), this function is rejected if you use the `decltype(expr)` as return type, as in this case SFINAE comes into picture. But if you use simply `auto`, then SFINAE doesn't come into picture and the error is classified to be a hard-error which results in compilation failure.
- The second overload which accepts `foo_t const&` as argument is called if SFINAE works in the first case.

Comment: Ah, I had not realized that the C++11 worked because the call to `base::fun` was rejected, and _then_ `derived::fun` was taken as a second choice.  Thanks a lot!  However, how come `decltype(auto)` does not fix the issue?  Should it be considered a bug in both GCC and Clang?

Comment: OK, I just read your comments to the question itself, and that make everything clear, many thanks!